# iOS Autofill from SMS passcodes not working on flutter web

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-web, autofill

According to [this page](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iphc89a3a3af/ios) iOS can read the sms codes and offer it on top of keyboard.

I use [a package](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_autofill) in my flutter app, that adds autofill=oneTimeCode in my input.

It works well on the iOS native app export, but not works on flutter web export, what's the problem?

[image]

I also checked the html code that exported by flutter, and there is `autocomplete="one-time-code"` here:

```
<input name="one-time-code" id="one-time-code" type="text" autocomplete="one-time-code" autocorrect="off" class="flt-text-editing transparentTextEditing" style="white-space: pre-wrap; align-content: center; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; padding: 0px; opacity: 1; color: transparent; background: transparent; outline: none; border: none; resize: none; overflow: hidden; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; caret-color: transparent; text-align: center; font: 1px On, Arial, sans-serif; width: 290px; height: 1px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 50.2, 221.5);">
```

I do not understand what's the problem

Is there any way to change `type="text"` to `type="tel"` or `type="number"` in the exported html code by flutter?

Answer (score 1):

Update: This is a known bug, and flutter team will fix this soon.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/104693